# how to isolate firefox 17 rendering bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have a curious little bug in some HTML that only show up in Firefox 17 (OSX 10.8.2, no other OS tested yet). I have a 'sidebar' css class that encloses some text which is a repeating element on a number of pages. On one page (only) this text renders as if it has its css visiblility property set to 'hidden' (it does not display, but leaves the correct space around itself).

[image]
<sup>**left** Firefox 16.0.2; **right** Firefox 17.0.1</sup>

Here is the css class:

```
.sidebar {
      position:fixed; 
      top: 2px;
      left:4px;
      display:table-cell; 
      vertical-align:bottom;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 700px;
      height: 64px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(320px) translateY(340px) scale(1);
      -moz-transform:    rotate(90deg) translateX(320px) translateY(340px) scale(1);
      -o-transform:      rotate(90deg) translateX(320px) translateY(340px) scale(1);
      -ms-transform:     rotate(90deg) translateX(320px) translateY(340px) scale(1);
      transform:         rotate(90deg) translateX(320px) translateY(340px) scale(1);      
}
```

The affected HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar" >
    <span class="TMUP1">
        <a href="/">Section_Header</a>
    </span> 
    <span class="sidebarcontents" style="vertical-align: 50%">
        Subsection_Header
    </span>
</div>
```

All pages on the site contain an identical piece of google analytics asynchronous tracking javascript. If I remove this code, the bug disappears. I have checked the code and it is correct. It is used on every page in the site, and all other pages, with the SAME html (it's a repeating header) render fine

The google js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-000000-0']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

The bug disappears under any of the following conditions
 - viewed in firefox 16 (same user settings and plugins), or any other browser.
 - viewed in firefox 17 / safe mode
 - remove the google analytics code
 - replace the following line from the 'sidebar' class css

```
 -moz-transform:    rotate(90deg) translateX(320px) translateY(340px) scale(1);
```

with

```
 -moz-transform:    translateX(320px) translateY(340px) scale(1);
```

(i.e remove the rotation)

It has nothing to do with plugins and addons, as if I manually disable all of these the bug is still evident.

Other pages with the same HTML, same css and the same google analytics code render fine.

The problem page is the largest on the site (~10KB of optimised/gzipped html with around 160 small images / 880KB to load), all other pages are smaller.

The body is almost entirely made up of 160 repeats of this element

```
<div class= "outerDiv" style="background-color:transparent">
<div class="innerDiv">
    <a href='/artists/artist_name/'>
    <img src="/artists/artist_name/_portrait/artist_portrait.jpg" alt="" width="150" />
    </a>
<div class="short_caption">
    <a href='/artists/artist_name/' style="color:white">artist_name</a>
<br />artist_location
</div></div></div>
```

If I drastically cut the number of these elements down this also fixes the bug.

Any ideas how to further isolate/fix the bug? At the moment it seems like i'd have to either sacrifice analytics or redesign the site, both of which seem a little excessive.

**update**

I've done a lot more investigating, and got it down to this.

- it's nothing to do with the google javascript. ANY script, even an empty `<script></script>` will invoke the bug.
- I am using custom fonts with @font-face pulled in from a linked stylesheet.

  - If i only use system fonts, the bug disappears.
  - if I move the @font-face rules from a linked stylesheet into the page header the bug becomes more resilient: it shows up regardless of the presence of script tags
- turn off hardware acceleration, the bug disappears.
- remove rotation from the transform, the bug disappears.
- reduce the page size (from 160 images to around 10) and the bug disappears.
- Firefox nightly (v20) does not show the bug so whatever is causing it is fixed in some future version after v17.0.1

Here are some sample pages showing the issue (I'd avoided them in the original question as I guess that linking is a little frowned upon here). Browser cache needs to be emptied between each page view to gauge the bug effect accurately

- [original page](http://www.tweet-me-up.com/artists/) bug present
- [test page](http://www.tweet-me-up.com/artists/_test.html) bug present

  - simplified html and minimised css to isolate the bug
  - no javascript but one empty `<script></script>` tag

These samples are all derived from the test page:

- [`<script></script>` tag removed](http://www.tweet-me-up.com/artists/_test_no_javascript_tag.html) bug absent
- [rotation removed from transform](http://www.tweet-me-up.com/artists/_test_no_rotation.html) bug absent
- [page size reduced from 160 to 18 images](http://www.tweet-me-up.com/artists/_test_shortened.html) bug absent
- [no custom fonts](http://www.tweet-me-up.com/artists/_test_system_fonts.html) bug absent
- [internal stylesheet for custom fonts](http://www.tweet-me-up.com/artists/_test_internal_font_styles.html) bug present

  - this is a weird one. If the @font_face stylesheet is external, the bug only shows if a `<script></script>` tag is present. If the @font_face rules are moved to an internal stylesheet, the bug is also evident in the absence of `<script></script>` tags.

I can't seem to eliminate the bug without changing the design of the page to such a degree I'd have to redesign the site which seems a little OTT for one version of one browser. I am hoping for a more practical workaround. I tried using jQuery browser sniffing but as javascript seems to introduce the bug that's a non-starter.

**update 2**

Now I have had a chance to test on a different machine, and find the bug is manifest very rarely. Testing as a new user on the original machine doesn't display the bug at all. So it is clearly something to do with user settings and - hopefully then - fairly rare.

**update 3**

Following a suggestion by @Boris, I have tried incremental rotation to see where and how the page is breaking up. It is fine from rotate(0deg) until about 80deg, after which it starts to fall apart. I've added 1px borders to all elements to help isolate the issue...

- [sample pages](http://www.tweet-me-up.com/artists/_test_rotations.html) showing 0-90deg (they should bounce from one to the next on auto refresh).
  This is using `-moz-transform` so only worth looking at in Firefox.
- [animation](http://www.screencast.com/users/washe/folders/Jing/media/c21d81b1-f15e-46fa-93f6-75da9e72932e): this is the result I am getting in firefox 17.0.1

**update 4**

answering some suggestions from @arttronics - here is a [3d firefox view](http://screencast.com/t/FsvVZEm5G3Dp) showing how it should stack up (when I switch to 3d view, the bug disappears, as if Firefox is trying just that little bit harder to do the right thing).

- the protuding content seen in the 3D view is for text alignment, it does not affect the bug - [see this cut-down version](http://www.screencast.com/t/6ac6yoYp);
- zoom is reset, no change;
- a new user profile exhibits same behaviour.

**update 5 – reset Firefox**

After performing a Firefox reset (as per @arttronics' answer) the bug is still here, albeit perhaps a little less resilient.

Prior to reset this would invoke the bug
- clear the cache
- refresh the page

Post-reset, clearing the cache and refreshing brings up the bug about 50% of the time. If I clear the cache, restart firefox, return to the page - it is still there, every time.

---

Ok I'm going to answer my own question ... I have not found a solution, but thanks to the interest and amazing efforts of the stack overflow community it seems fairly clear to me that...

- this may be an issue that is very hard to replicate beyond the peculiarities of my user setup
- it's an obscure bug only manifest in Firefox 17.0.1 and apparently fixed in Firefox 18
- there is no workaround that doesn't involve a site redesign

Therefore, in the interests of moving on with other issues, I suggest we put this question to rest! Thanks to everyone who made comments and suggestions, it's been a very educational process.

Comment: a code is worth a thousand words : )

Comment: AdBlock? Ghostery? Any one of your extensions could be causing this problem. Especially since the code works in "safe mode", which disables all extensions and toolbars.

Comment: @akonsu, point taken, code added!

Comment: @Soumya, as I pointed out in the question, I disabled every extension  and plug-in manually (Tools>Add-ons 'disable' for each one) and the bug remains. What else does 'safe mode' switch off?

Comment: reduce your case even more. Remove everything that you can, from both css and html, while ensuring bug still reproduces. Also, check if it reproduces in firefox nightly (current version is 20). Then - submit it to mozilla's bugzilla ;)

Comment: If safe mode works...  Does disabling hardware acceleration also make the bug go away?

Comment: @c69, the bug does not appear in firefox nightly. It's not the google code either, an empty script tag will have the same effect. I'm following your advice and whittling away at the html and css to find a minimum case. I'll amend the question as I find out more...

Comment: @Boris, how do I disable hardware acceleration (osx..)?

Comment: Disabled hardware acceleration (i was looking in the wrong tab in 'advanced prefs') - the bug disappears.

Comment: @HeWas OK.  It's hard to say what an effective workaround is without seeing the actual markup, unfortunately.  :(

Comment: @Boris, I've posted an update with links to sample pages showing the bug

Comment: @c69, I've reduced the case considerably and posted an update with links to sample pages... I haven't any thoughts on a workaround yet.

Comment: @HeWas Does rotating by 89.9 degrees instead of 90 work around the problem?

Comment: @Boris - No 89.9 degrees doesn't help, but your comment has inspired me to dig a little further, see update_3

Comment: @HeWas, Consider using **built in** `Firefox 3D View` to look at layered CSS. Right mouse-click webpage and choose `Inspect Element (Q)` and press the `3D View Button`. More info [**HERE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/3D_view).  Also, you are using obsolete `border` attribute in HTML, as noted [**HERE**](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tweet-me-up.com%2Fartists%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3).

Comment: @arttronics, good suggestion - see my update with a 3d view. It doesn't really teach me anything though - when I switch to 3d view, the bug disappears, as if Firefox is trying just that little bit harder to do the right thing. I know that 'border' is obsolete in the IMG tag - but the page is generated by a perl script which has to work with some legacy cruft, so I have left it in for now. Removing it doesn't fix the bug...

Comment: @HeWas, Consider placing an image of this issue without `3D view`, as I am not able to see this bug and am not sure how it looks. As for `3D View`, just in case the `light blue` section under the `green text` logo section is protruding ***outside the area*** to the left side. Something else to try, from Firefox `Menu` choose `View` and then `Zoom` and ensure you have NO checkmark on `Text Only` and then select `Reset Zoom`. Finally, since a New PC User on the PC causes no issues, create a [**New Firefox User Profile**](http://goo.gl/QB1vL) on the troubled PC User account and test website again

Comment: @arttronics - thanks for your suggestions - see update 4 + added images.

Comment: @arttronics - i've added pictures (with and without the bug) at the _top_ of the question

Comment: Idea 1: Since this bug is only on 1 webpage, the page with about 160 objects on it, why not add 160 objects to a different test page that doesn't have this issue to see if that page too has the problem. Then, it's clear that 1 page is not the issue but the whole site is affected with this condition.

Comment: Idea 2: On the troubled page, try accessing that webpage with `https:\\www` and `http:\\www.` and finally `without www.`  Perhaps this bug is related to how the page is initially accessed, for whatever reason. TIP: Create desktop shortcuts with unique names to reflect how the webpage is accessed, so you can open/close the browser directly multiple times.

Comment: @arttronics - Idea 1 - I moved the page to a different part of the site, and I took a different page and increased the number of objects, the behaviour is the same. Idea 2 - I have tried accessing via `http://www` (amazon cached version, nginx server), `http://real` (non-cached version, apache server) and the development site version, all exhibit the same behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reset Firefox**

Based on your detailed question and the resulting comments, this particular bug is only unique to you, and under certain conditions (new OS User Profile has no issues while new Firefox User Profile has issues).

It's then time to **Reset** Firefox. Just [**follow these simple steps**](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems) and your v17.0.1 should be back to normal. If you have multiple profiles for your Firefox installation, then [**follow these other steps**](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/933275?esab=a&s=reset+button+missing&r=2&as=s) instead.

***NOTE: When using the reset feature, your bookmarks, browsing history, passwords, cookies and web form auto-fill information will be saved. However, your extensions and themes will be removed; open tabs, windows and tab groups will not be saved; and your preferences will be reset.***

---

**EDIT: Per my comments written the other day:**

> As of yet I did not see anybody reply that they too see this logo
>   sinkhole issue, but at lease Firefox 18 ETA is in 3 weeks as of this
>   comment.

Having said that, the solution may be just to wait until **Firefox 18** is released.

Comment: Accepted! I upvoted already. You have been most helpful, thankyou ;-j